# Can VS 2015 Ent connect to multiple TFS instances?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have been using TFS for a while with dot.net builds and a large # of sql databases .   Now we have some Azure Cloud implementations on a different TFS instance.   I need to use both instances and am using a Web version of TFS to access the Cloud TFS now.   I would like to connect my Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 client to both TFS instances.   When I tried to connect to the Cloud instance of TFS it looked like it was going to forget my current TFS server, so I stopped.  So can I connect my client VS 2015 Enterprise to more than one TFS instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can switch between instances of TFS/VSTS via the "Manage Connections" section of the Team Explorer.

However, you can only be connected to **one** instance at a time.